# Proving a statement in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'll directly quote a couple of lines from *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin:

> An ordered set $S$ has the least-upper-bound property if the following is true:
> If $E \subset S, E $ is not empty and is bounded above, then $sup E$ exists in S. We shall now show that there is a close relation between the greatest lower bound and the least upper bounds, and that every ordered set with the least-upper-bound property(which I'll hereafter refer to as LUB property) also has the greatest-lower-bound property(GLB property).

Drawing an analogy from the previous definition, I think this is what the GLB property is: *If $E \subset S, E $ is not empty and is bounded below, then $inf E$ exists in S.*
The author continues to describe a theorem and its proof:

> *Theorem* Suppose $S$ is an ordered set with the least-upper-bound property,$B \subset S, B $ is not empty and is bounded below. Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds of $B$. Then $\alpha = supL$ exists in $S$ and is equal to $infB$. In particular $infB$ exists in $S$.
> *Proof* Since B is bounded below, L is not empty. Since L consists of exactly those $y \in S$ satisfying $y \le x$ for every $x \in B$, every $x \in B$ is an upper bound of L. Thus L is bounded above. Our hypothesis about S implies therefore that L has a supremum in S; call it $\alpha$. If $\gamma < \alpha$ then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of L, hence $\gamma$ is not in B. Thus $\alpha \in L$. If $\alpha < \beta, \beta$ is not in L since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of L. We have shown that $\alpha \in L$ but $\beta$ is not in L if $\beta > \alpha$. In other words $\alpha$ is a lower bound of B, but $\beta$ is not if  $\beta > \alpha$. This means that $\alpha = infB$.

I think we are trying to show here is that since $S$ has the LUB property, it also has the GLB property.

1. If so, its clear from the definition that $B$ should be bounded *above* and not below, unlike what's stated in the theorem.
2. *'Our hypothesis about S implies therefore that L has a supremum in S.'* This is definitely a conclusion of the LUB property, but how can we be so certain that $L \subset S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why? You wrote yourself that that the GLB property is “If $E\subset S$, $E$ is not empty and is bounded below, then $\inf E$ exists in $S$.”
2. Because everything here is taking place in $S$.

Comment: Um, no. In 1 I wrote about the part of the statement that's given, i.e. the part which tells us that it had the LUB property. As for 2, if i consider S to be the set of all natural numbers and B to be the set containing 1,2,3, L won't belong to S.(Right?)

Comment: Concerning 1, I think that you are asserting one thing and it's opposite. You wrote that asserting that the GLB property is about $B$ being bounded from below, and then you say that it should be bounded from above. Again: what Rudin is proving is that if $B$ is non-empty and bounded from below, then $\inf B$ exists. Concerning 2, if $S=\Bbb N$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$, then $L=\{y\in\Bbb N|(\forall x\in B):y\leqslant x\}$ which is *by definition* a subset of $L(=\Bbb N)$. In this case, $L=\{1\}$.

Comment: Right, if that's what he's proving it all adds up. But remember that he mentioned he wanted to prove that every ordered set with the LUB property also has the GLB property. What I'm trying to convey is that if the set S does have the LUB property(that's a given), B should be bounded above. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm reading the book for the first time, perhaps your answer would make sense to me if i come back to the discussion in a while.

Comment: It *does* make sense. But Rudin applies the LUB property to $L$ (which is bounded from above), not to $B$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The key part here is that we are showing $L$ has a least upper bound, not $B$. So, in order to use the fact that $S$ has the LUB property, we need to show that $L$ (and not $B$) is bounded above and nonempty. This is where the assumption that $B$ is bounded *below* comes in: since $L$ is the set of all lower bounds of $B$, the fact that $B$ is bounded below tells us $L$ is nonempty.

The theorem can be summarized as follows: the least upper bound of all the lower bounds ($\text{sup} \; L$) is the greatest lower bound ($\text{inf} \; B$).

2. When the author writes $E \subset S$ is bounded above, it really means $E$ is bounded above by some element of $S.$ So, when we define $L$ to be the set of all lower bounds of $B,$ what is really meant is that $L$ is the set of all lower bounds of $B$ in $S$. The fact that $L \subset S$ follows directly from this.

Comment: I've got 1. About 2, if i consider S to be the set of all natural numbers and B to be the set containing 1 2 3 L won't belong to S.(right?) Or have I got it all wrong?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind I think the key issue here is that when we say $L,$ we mean the lower bounds of $B$ *that are also in* $S.$ So, by definition, $L$ is a subset of $S$. Let's look at your example, where $S = \mathbb{N}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3\}.$ The lower bounds of $B$ that are also in $S$ are $0$ and $1$ (if you don't count $0$ as a natural number, then just $1$). So here, we would have $L = \{0, 1\}$, which is a subset of $S = \mathbb{N}.$